# Avoid including bootstrap min.css & .css with wiredep

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gulp, wiredep

I'm writing a script with wiredep & gulp but I have a an unexpected result at the the end when I include Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Why wiredep is including both .css & min.css files? And why bootstrap-theme is also included?

Thanks

Comment: Awesome find! I have never heard of wiredep. Can you also provide us with your current gulpfile.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from a bad override in my bower.json:

Before it was:

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
            "dist/js/*.*",
            "dist/css/*.*",
            "dist/fonts/*.*"
        ]
    }
```

Fixed one is:

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
            "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "dist/fonts/*.*"
        ]
    }
```

This overrides is needed for 3.3.5 and should not be needed anymore with 3.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I use bindep instead wiredep. It is more professional , with many features but above all it permits to overcome the bower limits using bower.

npm install bindep